# Remove all options from bootstrap select multiselect

Tags: jquery, multi-select, bootstrap-select

I am using the [boostrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) jQuery plugin, which is dynamically populated based on the user's choice. But every time I populate the multiselect with an option set, the old ones must be deleted, so there won't be any duplicates.
But removing the options is not working, and I can't find anything in the documentation of the plugin. I've googled a lot and tried every solution but nothing works.

This is my select :

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" name="department_id" multiple data-live-search="true">
</select>
```

I am using :

- Bootstrap 5
- Bootstrap-select v1.14.0-beta3

**Solution**
Bootstrap-select v1.14.0-beta3 seems to have bug, but v1.14.0-beta2 is working fine with the following code:

```js
// remove the options
$('#department_id option').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

First I built an example then I looked at the documentation. Actually the latter would have been enough. The proper selectpicker [method](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/) is `refresh`

```js
var select = document.querySelector("[name=department_id]");
var i=1

function addOption() {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.text = "hello #" + i++
  select.appendChild(option);
  $(select).selectpicker('refresh')
}

function removeAllOptions() {
  select.innerHTML = "";
  $(select).selectpicker('refresh')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="form-control selectpicker" name="department_id" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option>hello</option>
  <option>world</option>
</select>
<hr>


<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addOption()">add option</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="removeAllOptions()">remove all options</button>
```

Comment: does not work with Bootstrap 5

Comment: yes [bootstrap select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) only supports bootstrap 3 and 4

Comment: that's not good. I like it because it sets a checkmark next to the selected item :(

Comment: their [new version](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/releases/tag/v1.14.0-beta2) (which is now on a pre-release status or beta) will support bootstrap 5

Comment: I am using bootstrap5 with v1.14.0-beta3, but the code you provided does not work with this version. Options are not deleted.

Comment: ok using v1.14.0-beta2 does work fine with the `remove` method