# Trying to empty a bootstrap-select and repopulate

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying to delete all the  values in a multiselect selectpicker from bootstrap-select (https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) but it doesn't work no matter what I try.

I have tried following the examples from the remove method found in methods in the link provided above.

I have also tried using `.empty()` followed by `.selectpicker('refresh')` which only removes the first  but when I click the second  in the list, it shows the value of the first (removed)  as selected.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/asjnpLkh/1/

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
It seems the problem was with beta3 version of bootstrap-select. Using beta2 works fine. [Remove all options from bootstrap select multiselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74247689/remove-all-options-from-bootstrap-select-multiselect)